# Book where the main character has healing powers but the love interest makes them sick

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I think it was regency era fantasy YA and the main character had healing powers but it was believed that her friend actually possessed them. The love interest made people sick by being near them/ touching them but the main character is the only person that can counteract this. Some sort of secret society.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character or place names, or details of the cover art?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any of the following.

Could it be [one of Amanda Quick's "The Arcane Society" novels](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57569-arcane-society)?  I haven't read one that sounds like that, only the one with the photographer and the one with the lady with plant powers, but it sounds like it might be one.  They're set in Victorian times (rather than Regency, but close), they involves a secret society of people with psychic powers, each person generally has only one specific power, and they're romantic novels.

The secret society is also informally known as "the Jones society", if that helps - founded by an alchemist called Sylvester Jones and most of the members are his descendants.

There don't seem to be any on Goodreads's list of the books in the series that obviously match that plot, though.  And they're not particularly YA.